# How Can I Redefine a Classs Outside of A Loop?

Tags: c++, class, redefinition

I am getting redefinition of class error for the below code. But if I put this definition in a loop there is no error. What  is the difference?

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyClass
{
    int x;
};


int main()
{
    MyClass A;
    MyClass A;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this but still there is same redefinition error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyClass
{
    int x;
};


int main()
{
    MyClass* A;
    delete(A);
    MyClass* A;
    delete(A);
    return 0;
}
```

However If I put it **in a loop no problem** at all:

```
using namespace std;

struct MyClass
{
    int x;
};


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        MyClass A;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So what is the difference? And how can I delete and redefine a class with the same name. I don't want to find different names. I will use it outside of a loop and push_back those in a vector.

What I want to do is actually:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct MyClass
{
    int x;
    // other variables vectors etc.
};


vector <MyClass> v_A;

int main()
{
    MyClass A;
    // Use A's methods and give values to its variables and vectors.
    v_A.push_back(A);

    MyClass A2;
    // Use A's DIFFERENT methods and give values to its variables and vectors.
    v_A.push_back(A2);

    MyClass A3;
    // Use A's AGAIN DIFFERENT methods and give values to its variables and vectors.
    v_A.push_back(A3);

    // Goes on. I don't want to create different objects A A2 A3 ... A30. I don't want to keep them in the memory.
    // I don't want to write 2 3 ... 30
    // Is there a way to get rid of them from memory?

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATING THE CODE TO INCLUDE A SOLUTION DEPENDING ON linsock's ANSWER:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct MyClass
{
    int x;
    // other variables vectors etc.
};


vector <MyClass> v_A;

int main()
{
    {
        MyClass A;
        // Use A's methods and give values to its variables and vectors.
        v_A.push_back(A);
    }

    {
        MyClass A;
        // Use A's DIFFERENT methods and give values to its variables and vectors.
        v_A.push_back(A);
    }

    {
        MyClass A;
        // Use A's AGAIN DIFFERENT methods and give values to its variables and vectors.
        v_A.push_back(A);
    }

    // Goes on. I dont want to create different classes A A2 A3 ... A30. I dont want to keep them in the memory.
    // I dont want to write 2 3 ... 30
    // Is there a way to get rid of them from memeory?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are re-declaring A two times , instead , just assign the new value.
`MyClass * A = new MyClass();`
`delete A;`
`A = new MyClass();`

Comment: `delete(A);` Do you have a Python background?

Comment: @ fvalasiad This time it gives the error : 'A': redefinition; multiple initialization

Comment: @Ayxan Haqverdili No I don't.

Comment: Note: `using namespace std;` before you've included any `std` header files is pointless. You may also want to take a look at [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here

```
    MyClass A;
    MyClass A;
```

you're defining the same class variable twice (which by the way should be highlighted by your compiler with a great compilation failure message)

The same you're doing here, but worse

```
 MyClass* A;
 delete(A);
 MyClass* A;
 delete(A);
```

since you're also trying to delete the pointer you defined but never initialized to point to a valid memory area.

In the last case of the for loop (which could be any block scope for what concern object creation/destruction) you're creating a stack allocated object, which internally contains only primitive types, then each cycle it gets created and destroyied with default ctor/dtor provided by the compiler.

I would suggest you to find a good tutorial to better understand how you're supposed to deal with this kind of behaviors in C++ .

**EDIT from comments**:
delete will delete the data pointed-by the pointer you're trying to delete.
If you want to define the same variable one after the other you should define the first in a block-scoped section  in this way

```
 {
     MyClass* A;
 }
 MyClass* A;
```

In this way, the inner-defined `MyClass* A` will be lost after the exit from the scope and you can define it in the outer scope.

Even if this is actually possible, I would suggest you don't do that to enhance code readability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May be I should have asked how can I get rid of a class initialized. delete is not enough apparently.

Comment: I updated my answer to better answer your doubt (which wouldn't fit well in a comment)

Answer (score 2):

Here you are trying to create two objects with the same name:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass A;
    MyClass A;
    return 0;
}
```

If that had worked, you would not be able to differentiate between the two objects. Which `A` would `A.x = 10;` work on for example? The compiler doesn't know so it refuses to compile.

Here you are creating a new `MyClass` object in every loop that is destroyed at the closing `}`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    MyClass A;
    A.x = 10; // totally fine - there is only one `A` at a time
} // the A is destroyed here
```

---

The part where you are trying to use pointers should look like this to work:

```
int main() {
    MyClass* A = new MyClass;
    A->x = 10;                // example
    delete A;

    A = new MyClass;          // not "MyClass* A = ". A already exists
    A->x = 20;                // example
    delete A;
}
```

---

> Is there a way to get rid of them from memory?

What you get in the `vector` in your updated question are *copies*. The automatic instances you've created are destroyed at the end of the scope.

In your edited question, you don't even need any named `MyClass` object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass {
    int x;

    void foo() { std::cout << x << '\n'; }
    void bar() { std::cout << x*2 << '\n'; }
    void baz() { std::cout << x*3 << '\n'; }
};

std::vector <MyClass> v_A;

int main() {
    v_A.emplace_back(1);
    v_A.back().foo();    // calls foo() on the last element in the vector

    v_A.emplace_back(2);
    v_A.back().bar();    // calls a different method on the new object

    v_A.emplace_back(3);
    v_A.back().baz();    // calls a different method on the last object
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want to do after MyClass A use its methods produce values and v_A.push_back(A); . I repeat this by hand out of a loop with different ways. I dont want to use MyClass A2 and MyClass A3 and goes on A30.
I thought that there would be a way to clear the memory from "A" easily.

Comment: @KC_ You're welcome. I don't see the code you are talking about, but I assume you have a `std::vector<MyClass>`? In that case you don't even need a named object. You can `emplace_back(...MyClass constructor arguments...)` into the vector. You can also initialize the `vector` with all objects in one go if you know what to fill it with.

Comment: Yes it is. It is something like this:
vector<MyClass> v_A;
MyClass A;
// many lines;
v_A.push_back(A);:
MyClass A2;
// many diffrent lines;
v_A.push_back(A2):;
goes on.
Is there a way not to use A A2 ... A30. I dont want to keep them. I will already have their vector.

Comment: @KC_ Is [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q1P9c9) something you could work with?

Comment: @KC_ That's perfectly fine. No need to be sorry :-) If I haven't fully answered your question, you can [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66595964/edit) and provide more details and I'll try to address what you add.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you comment I think. I will check the web page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you're creating 2 variables of type `MyClass` with the same name inside the same `scope`, so evidently you're getting a redefinition error. In the second example the same occurs only that now the variables are pointers to `MyClass`, deleting them only frees the memory to which they were pointing at but the pointers still exist.
Finally in the `for` loop example you're constantly creating and destroying a 'MyClass` variable at every iteration of the loop, so no variables with the same name ever exist under the same scope.